# Where is qtmultimedia located?

Tags: qt

The docs mention how to include and link qtmultimedia:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-module.html#details

but looking at the maintenance tool:

[image]

there don't seem to be any intuitively named libraries. Where is qtmultimedia?

Comment: Note: QtMultimedia is not yet available in Qt6

Answer (score 1):

QMultimedia first beta has just been release at qt 6.2. [source](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-multimedia-in-qt-6).

You do not have to dowload further qt extension.

If you want to use it, you have to include `QMultimedia` and add the following code into qmake: `QT += multimedia`

Comment: is not working for me on QT6.3.1